# create new property in new object from linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

so I am doing a linq-to-sql query and the results come as an IEnumerable.  From this list I am creating a new object for each result that is returned.  The stored procedure that I am using already is returning the objects in the order that I want.   We have a leader board and the results are in descending order after the query. the part I am having problems with is I want to add the ranking into a new property in the new object.

say I have this code

```
 var usersSummary = Context.[myStoredProcedure]
            return usersSummary.Select(x => new [myObject]
            {
                UserId = x.UserID,
                FirstName = x.FirstName,
                LastName = x.LastName,
                TotalPoints = x.TotalPoints,
                LeaderBoardRank = //this part here
                Email = x.Email,
                CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate
            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPoints).ToList();
```

I would like the `LeaderBoardRank` to be their ranking.  They are already sorted in ranking order , so the first object would be 1 , the next 2 , and so on.  Since this is not a normal c# loop im not too sure how to fill this property with the ranking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "new property" you mean that `LeaderBoardRank` id NOT a property of `myObject` then no, you can't do that.  You either need to define another class (possibly that extends `MyObject`) or use an anonymous type, either with that additional property or with two properties - the rank and the object.

If `LeaderBoardRank` is *already* a property and you want to add the rank of the sorted result, you can do it this way:

```
var usersSummary = Context.[myStoredProcedure];

return usersSummary.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPoints)
                   .Select((x, i) => new [myObject]
{
    UserId = x.UserID,
    FirstName = x.FirstName,
    LastName = x.LastName,
    TotalPoints = x.TotalPoints,
    LeaderBoardRank = i
    Email = x.Email,
    CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate
}).ToList();
```

Note that this does NOT account for ties - meaning if two users have the same total points they will not have the same rank.

Comment: didn't get a chance to test yesterday , worlks great though , thanks

Answer (score 3):

`Select` as an overload with an index that you can use.

```
    var usersSummary = Context.[myStoredProcedure]
        return usersSummary.Select((x, i) => new [myObject]
        {
            UserId = x.UserID,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            TotalPoints = x.TotalPoints,
            LeaderBoardRank = i
            Email = x.Email,
            CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPoints).ToList();
```

Is the object you're creating already the object you have in your list? In this case you don't have to create a new object but just assign the value to the existing one:

```
    var usersSummary = Context.[myStoredProcedure]
        return usersSummary.Select((x, i) => 
            {
                x.LeaderBoardRank = i;
                return x;
            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPoints).ToList();
```

Also if your list is already ordered there's no need to order it again. The order will not be changed by your select statement.

Comment: I'm gonna try this out now - it is a actual new object , and the sorting is for after the object is created , after ranking is assigned, then I want to order by total points - which is actually different the ranking

Comment: Will this overload work for the given query provider.  I know at least some of them cannot implement a select with an indexer.

Comment: @Servy Unfortunately this overload won't work with Linq-to-sql or Linq-to-entities. It would be useful and could be implemented in Sql, but it's not supported yet. For Linq-to-entities you could add a request on the Codeplex site or even implement it yourself (EF6 Alpha is open source).

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow Then this answer won't work.  You'll need to perform the query without the indexer on the database, do the ordering, then add `AsEnumerable` and use the `Select` with an indexer to add in that property.

Comment: @Servy It would be new to me that you can wrap Sql around the execution of stored procedures, therefor you don't get an IQueryable from the called stored procedure in code and the select statement won't alter the query. But I have to admin I'm not familiar with Linq-to-sql, but with EF it would be this case and my solution would work.