# Add New property to objects in List and return new List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I add a new property to a list of Person object and return the new List in linq?

```
List<person> persons = GetPersonList();
```

Its class is shown below

```
public class Person
{
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

While using linq I want to add another property (IsMale=true) which set true to all.

I don't want to do `select new {prop1= p.Name,IsMale=true}` . ie I want to avoid selecting all other properties to create this new one. Is this possible?

I'm looking how to do it with less code. Not just a how!

Now I'm doing it as below

```
select new {p,IsMale=true}
```

But in this case all old properties are inside p.
In real context the Person object is large one, so I have to avoid doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527089/create-new-property-in-new-object-from-linq)

Comment: I don't think you can get any better then selecting `new { p, IsMale = true }`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek is that impossible in linq?

Comment: You can't do it. An anonymous type you don't want to use is as far as you can get to the desired result.

Comment: @SubinJacob You'd have to specify all existing properties of `Person` class in your code, and that's what you don't want to do. You could try using reflection, but I don't think it's a good idea. And I don't see anything more to do here.

Comment: Do you need to do this only once or would you use this desired functionality more often?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek only once. i just wanted to avoid that a in between. Now its a.Name and IsMale! I want Name and IsMale

Comment: @OndrejJanacek i WANT IT BECAUSE, i CAN WRITE IT BETTER IN FUTURE

Comment: are you saying that I want something unwanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you asking for is more often a feature of [Dynamic Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language). In C# the options that you listed are as good as it gets. At least in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use dynamic linq with reflection to achieve this .A good example is shown below

[Create new PropertyInfo object on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641339/create-new-propertyinfo-object-on-the-fly)